# How can I write a query to return results with no Nulls?

Tags: sql

I want to query a DB with lots of columns and want only those rows which do not contain a NULL.

How can I write this query?

Comment: use `is not null` in your `WHERE` condition

Comment: Check every NULLable column, no shorter way for this exists.

Answer (score 1):

Use `is not null`. For instance:

```
SELECT [col1] FROM [YourTable]
WHERE [col1] is not null
```

Answer (score -1):

If my understanding is correct, you want to get a record which do not have ANY NULL column.

A way to build dynamically the 'WHERE' clause is using sys.columns like this

```
Select 'AND', Name, 'IS NOT NULL' from sys.columns where object_id in 
(select object_id from sys.objects where name like 'TABLE-NAME' and type='U')
```

By this you can just add all these lines to your WHERE clause on

```
Select * from TABLE-NAME WHERE **list of clauses here**
```